# What is with these pervert Bobokins?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Every time I ask Fi to analyze a Bobokin, she tells me how they have a fascination with "fashionable undergarments". She says this about every single one, Red Bobokins, Green Bobokins, Archer Bobokins, Electric Bobokins, Cursed Bobokins...

At first the anecdotes about these creatures' fascination with underwear was amusing. But now it's just disturbing... Does this have any actual plot significance? Or is it just a joke that wears thin as the game progresses?

Comment: I thought this had something to do with the skull treasure you can get from them (I think you can see it around their waist?), but I also remember something about trinket fascination... I won't have access to the game for a while, so I can't check :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific tidbit is simply colour commentary. It has no impact on the game or plot whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I should be annoyed that they put so much emphasis on something that doesn't actually matter, or relieved that Link doesn't have to strip to his undies and run through a gauntlet of Bobokins as one of the Spirit Trials...

Comment: *cough*.. Japanese hentai.. *cough*...